# Hoeffding’s formula for Locally most powerful rank tests

Tags: nonparametric, joint-distribution, order-statistics, ranks

Suppose we have a testing problem with $$H_0: X_1,X_2, . . . ,X_n \ \text{are i.i.d. random variables with a continuous cdf} \ F(x) \ \text{and pdf} \ f(x)$$ and $$H_1: X_1,X_2, . . . ,X_n \ \text{are independent random variables with} \ X_i \ \text{having a continuous cdf} \ F_i \ \text{and pdf} \ f_i, \text{respectively}.$$ Then the Hoeffding's formula says that $$\mathbb{P}_{H_1}(\underline{R}=\underline{r})=\mathbb{P}_{H_1}(R_1=r_1,....,R_n=r_n)=\int....\int \prod^n_{i=1}f_i(x_i)dx_i$$ where the integration is over the region $−\infty < x_{i_1} < x_{i_2} < . . . < x_{i_n} < \infty$ such that $X_i$ has rank $r_i$, that is, $x_i$ occupies the $r^{th}_i$ place in the above order, $i = 1, 2, . . . , n$. And then the proof goes like $$\mathbb{P}_{H_1}(\underline{R}=\underline{r})=\frac{1}{n!}\int....\int\frac{\prod^n_{i=1}f_{r_i}(x_{r_i})}{\prod^n_{i=1}f(x_i)}n!\prod^n_{i=1}f(x_i)dx_i=\frac{1}{n!}\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{f_{r_i}(X_{(r_i)})}{f(X_{(i)})}].$$ where the expectation $\mathbb{E}$ is with respect to the joint distribution of the order statistics $X_{(1)},X_{(2)}, . . . ,X_{(n)}$ of a random sample from $F(x)$.
$$$$Now if we go backwards, then to compute $\frac{1}{n!}\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{f_{r_i}(X_{(r_i)})}{f(X_{(i)})}]$ let $h$ be a function such that $h(y_1,....y_n)=\frac{1}{n!}\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{f_{r_i}(y_{r_i})}{f(y_{i})}$, then $$\frac{1}{n!}\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{f_{r_i}(X_{(r_i)})}{f(X_{(i)})}]=\mathbb{E}[h(X_{(1)},....,X_{(n)}]$$ where the expectation is with respect to the joint distribution of the order statistics $X_{(1)},X_{(2)}, . . . ,X_{(n)}$ of a random sample from $F(x)$. Now $$\mathbb{E}[h(X_{(1)},....,X_{(n)}]=\int....\int_S h(y_1,...y_n)n!\prod^n_{i=1}f(y_i)dy_i=\int....\int_S \frac{1}{n!}\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{f_{r_i}(y_{r_i})}{f(y_{i})} n!\prod^n_{i=1}f(y_i)dy_i \\ = \int....\int_S \prod_{i=1}^nf_{r_i}(y_{r_i})\prod^n_{i=1}dy_i=\int....\int_S \prod_{i=1}^nf_i(y_i)\prod^n_{i=1}dy_i=\mathbb{P}_{H_1}(X_1<X_2<....X_n)$$ where $S=\{(y_1,....y_n):y_1<y_2<....y_n)\}$. So I want to know that what is wrong in my computation? Also is it true that $X_{(R_i)}=X_i$ with probability $1$, because for any $\omega$, $R_i(\omega)$ is the rank of $X_i(\omega)$ and so $X_{(R_i(\omega))}(\omega)=X_i(\omega)$ and so $X_{(R_i)}=X_i$.